# click button in the excel file using C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have excel file and it has export button in the header. When we open excel and click on export a macro runs in background and exports excel to some location.

I am writing C# winform application which is wrapper over this excel file. This winform application has Export button. When user clicks on winform button C# code should open the excel file and programmatically click export button in the excel file and file is exported.

I am using OLEDBConnection to connect the excel file.  How to click button in the excel file using C#?

I have code to to read data from excel.

```
private void CreateConnectionString()
        {
            ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties="
                    + "\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=3;READONLY=FALSE\"";
        }

private void ReadDataFromExcelAndShowInGrid()
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            string sql = "Select * From [TimeSheet$]";
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Data");
                }
            }

            DataRowCollection dataRows = dataSet.Tables["Data"].Rows;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.Count; ++i)
            {
                string cDateTime = ConvertAndReturnStringToDateTime(dataRows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy");
                if (cDateTime != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (EndOfWeek.Equals(cDateTime))
                    {
                        var date = ConvertAndReturnStringToDateTime(dataRows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
                        var start = ConvertAndReturnStringToDateTime(dataRows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                        var stop = ConvertAndReturnStringToDateTime(dataRows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                        table.Rows.Add(cDateTime, date,
                            start, stop,
                            dataRows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString(), dataRows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString(),
                            dataRows[i].ItemArray[6].ToString(), dataRows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString(),
                            dataRows[i].ItemArray[8].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
private string ConvertAndReturnStringToDateTime(string dateTimeFromFile, string dateFormat)
        {
            string dateTime = string.Empty;

            double fileDateweek = 0.0d;
            if (double.TryParse(dateTimeFromFile, out fileDateweek))
            {
                dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(fileDateweek).ToString(dateFormat);
            }
            return dateTime;
        }
```

Comment: Can you clearly explain what is the purpose of export button in the excel ? You load data from DB and populate excel ?

Comment: Updated with code. @Kurubaran : Export excel file exports this file to some network location